# How to hide or show div elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have a selection block that contains three categories of elements and Divs associated with these categories. I want if we select a category, the divs associated with this category are displayed. Otherwise, let them remain hidden. I want the following divs: husband_name, number_pregnacy to be displayed only if we choose pregnant_wife. But when I do it, the husband_name div works correctelly, but not number_pregnacy. this is the code:

```
<div class="modal-body row">
                <form role="form" action="patient/addNew" class="clearfix" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('category'); ?></label>
                        <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="categorie" value='' id="category" onchange="changeCategorie()">

                            <option value="F#" > Sélect a category </option>
                            <option value="pregnant_wife" <?php
                            if (!empty($patient->category)) {
                                if ($patient->category== 'pregnantWife') {
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> > pregnant_wife </option>

                            <option value="Personnal" <?php
                            if (!empty($patient->category)) {
                                if ($patient->category== 'Personnal') {
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> > Personnal</option>
                            <option value="Other" <?php
                            if (!empty($patient->category)) {
                                if ($patient->category== 'Other') {
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> > Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('name'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('email'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="divUsband">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('name_husband'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_husband" id="nameUs" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="divEnfants">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('number_pregnancy'); ?></label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_pregnancy" id="numberPregnancy" placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('password'); ?></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="">
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('address'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('andtecedentMed'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentMed" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('andtecedentFam'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentFam" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('taille'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taille" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('poids'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poids" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('phone'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('sex'); ?></label>
                        <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="sex" value=''>

                            <option value="Masculin" <?php
                            if (!empty($patient->sex)) {
                                if ($patient->sex == 'Masculin') {
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> > Masculin </option>
                            <option value="Féminin" <?php
                            if (!empty($patient->sex)) {
                                if ($patient->sex == 'Féminin') {
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> > Féminin </option>
                            <option value="Autres" <?php
                            if (!empty($patient->sex)) {
                                if ($patient->sex == 'Autres') {
                                    echo 'selected';
                                }
                            }
                            ?> > Autres </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label><?php echo lang('birth_date'); ?></label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium default-date-picker" type="text" name="birthdate" value="" placeholder="" readonly="">      
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('blood_group'); ?></label>
                        <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="bloodgroup" value=''>
                            <?php foreach ($groups as $group) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $group->group; ?>" <?php
                                if (!empty($patient->bloodgroup)) {
                                    if ($group->group == $patient->bloodgroup) {
                                        echo 'selected';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?> > <?php echo $group->group; ?> </option>
                                    <?php } ?> 
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">    
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('doctor'); ?></label>
                        <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single"  name="doctor" value=''> 
                            <option value=""> </option>
                            <?php foreach ($doctors as $doctor) { ?>                                        
                                <option value="<?php echo $doctor->id; ?>"><?php echo $doctor->name; ?> </option>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </select>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group last col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Charger image</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                    <img src="//www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="btn btn-white btn-file">
                                        <span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-paper-clip"></i> Selectionner image</span>
                                        <span class="fileupload-exists"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Changer</span>
                                        <input type="file" class="default" name="img_url"/>
                                    </span>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Enlever</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--
                                        <div class="form-group last col-md-6">
                                            <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-md-12">
                                                <video id="video" width="200" height="200" autoplay></video>
                                                <div class="snap" id="snap">Capture Photo</div>
                                                <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
                                                Right click on the captured image and save. Then select the saved image from the left side's Select Image button.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                    -->


                    <!-- <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sms" value="sms"> <?php echo lang('send_sms') ?><br>
                    </div> -->


                    <section class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><?php echo lang('submit'); ?></button>
                    </section>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

and this is the JavaScript code:

```
var categorie = document.getElementById("categorie");
                            divUsband.style.display = 'none';
//                            divEnfants.style.display = 'none';


                            function changeCategorie() {
                                if (categorie.value == "FemmeEnceinte") {
                                    divUsband.style.display = 'block';
//                                    divEnfants.style.display = 'block';
                                } else {
                                    divUsband.style.display = 'none';
//                                    divEnfants.style.display = 'none';
                                }

                            }
```

I want to keep hiden these two divs: 






 until I select ***Pregnant_wife*** option

Comment: Just uncomment  the 3 divEnfants entries in the JS, like you did with the divUsband. And make sure you are getting the correct div before, like `var divEnfants = document.getElementById("divEnfants");`

Comment: @Cubakos I commented it because it didn't work.

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question title never needs "Hello everyone".

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have many mistakes in your HTML. When you use the id attribute on an element, it should be unique. No other element should have the same id. Your select elements do not have a value attribute. They get their values from the options element that the user selects. I have made some modifications to your html and I have a javascript script that will hide and show the husband and enfant div's.

```
<div class="modal-body row">
    <form role="form" action="patient/addNew" class="clearfix" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">

            </label>
            <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="categorie" value='' id="category">
                <option value="F#"> Sélect a category </option>
                <option value="pregnant_wife"> pregnant_wife </option>
                <option value="Personnal"> Personnal</option>
                <option value="Other"> Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Email
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="divUsband" style="display:none">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Husband Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_husband" id="nameUs" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="divEnfants" style="display:none">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Pregnancies
            </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_pregnancy" id="numberPregnancy" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Password
            </label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Address
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Medical History
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentMed" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Family History
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentFam" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Height
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taille" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Weight
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poids" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Phone
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value='' placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Sex
            </label>
            <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="sex" value=''>
                <option value="Masculin"> Masculin </option>
                <option value="Féminin"> Féminin </option>
                <option value="Autres"> Autres </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>
                Date of Birth
            </label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium default-date-picker" type="text"
                name="birthdate" value="" placeholder="" readonly="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Blood Type
            </label>
            <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="bloodgroup" value=''>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="AB">AB</option>
                <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                <option value="O">O</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                Doctor
            </label>
            <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="doctor" value=''>
                <option value="">-- Select a Doctor --</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group last col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Charger image</label>
            <div class="">
                <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                        <img src="//www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail"
                        style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="btn btn-white btn-file">
                            <span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-paper-clip"></i> Selectionner image</span>
                            <span class="fileupload-exists"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Changer</span>
                            <input type="file" class="default" name="img_url" />
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload"><i
                                class="fa fa-trash"></i> Enlever</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                Submit
            </button>
        </section>
    </form>

</div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Here is the javascript to handle showing and hiding the div's depending on what the user selected.

```
const category = document.getElementById('category');
const husband = document.getElementById('divUsband');
const enfant = document.getElementById('divEnfants');

category.addEventListener('change', evt => {
    let result = evt.target.value;

    if (result === 'pregnant_wife') {
        husband.style.display = '';
        enfant.style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        husband.style.display = 'none';
        enfant.style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

Comment: The `<label>` tags' `for` declarations are bad/misleading in your answer.

Comment: Ok for your help #Cavalier

Comment: @mickmackusa I just copied and pasted his code and removed some of his php script. I didn't comb through everything that was wrong.  But, Yes, I did miss his labels, as they were pointing to his duplicate ID attributes. Thanks for pointing that out.